# Request to 3rd party website in server logs

Tags: node.js, security, express

In my web server logs (I'm running node.js with express), intermixed with valid requests for files, I see the following:

```
[app-0 (out)] GET / 200 1ms - 3.95kb
[app-0 (out)] GET / 200 2ms - 3.95kb
[app-0 (out)] GET / 200 1ms - 3.95kb
---[app-0 (out)] GET http://www.mafengwo.com/ 200 1ms - 3.95kb
[app-0 (out)] GET / 304 1ms
```

I'm not the owner of "magengwo.com", and I'm unsure of how the attacker was able to query my web server for another website (and its a little more alarming that node responded with a 200). I would assume this is a bad thing, although I'm at a loss for how to reproduce this issue. Any help or explanation of whats going on here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In case people are curious, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525569/weird-http-request-found-in-the-node-js-express-log-file?rq=1 is related to this. Looks like the reply from my webserver is always the index. Doing "curl --proxy HOST_IP:PORT http://www.google.com" will show that this is the case. Why does this happen? I have absolutely no idea. However, it doesn't seem to be a vulnerability, at least.

Comment: I'm mind blown.  I'm seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same request within 15 minutes of spawning a testing server (SF on DigitalOcean), so I'm guessing it's a bot looking for subnodes serving mafengwo.com

Comment: I'm also getting this exact request on my DO nodes, I think this is the most plausible answer.

Comment: I agree, and am glad other people are seeing this as well. As I noted in my comment above, it's very disconcerting to see in the logs but I don't believe seeing it in the logs by itself is a sign of vulnerabilities.